# How to filter file list piped to xargs?

Tags: bash, scripting

My command: `git show --pretty="format:" --name-only` returns list of files.
Then I use xargs to run a shell script on those files:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only  | xargs -i phpmd $dir/'{}' text codesize,unusedcode,naming
```

However, I'd like to run that xargs command only on files with `.php` extension. How to filter the unwanted files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
... | grep '\.php$' | ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If your filenames may contain space or quotes, you should use GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ instead of xargs as xargs can lead to nasty surprises because of the separator problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#The_separator_problem:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only  | grep '\.php$' | parallel phpmd $dir/{} text codesize,unusedcode,naming
```

GNU Watch the intro video for GNU Parallel to learn more:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ